# Operation on "Assembly" is very slow when another application already use them

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I've some operation that I'm doing with reflection(this will be changed end of year, but in between I've to find a solution), so we load the DLL of one directory( with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`), then we filter it to check it contains some DLL.

The filter is based on some specific attribute present in the AssemblyInfo, then we check each type of the assembly(`assembly.GetTypes()`) and check it implements a specific interface.

If it does we instantiate the object and execute a method on it:

```
if (type.GetInterface(typeof(IAssemblyInitializer).FullName) == null)
{
    return ;
}
bool isCompatible = !type.IsAbstract;
if (!type.IsClass)
{
    return
}
if (type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]) == null)
{
    return
}

IAssemblyInitializer initializer = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[0]) as IAssemblyInitializer;
if (initializer != null)
{
    initializer.InitializeAssembly();
}
```

Everything seems to work, but when we have another application already started(and having done this exact same procedure), the execution of this takes a lot longer(like 2 minutes instead of 20 seconds).

So my question: Why does it seems we are influenced on the fact that another application has already loaded thoses assemblies, and what can we do against ?

Thanks!

Comment: If I were you I'd try to isolate the line(s) that seem to be causing the delay, by timing them in both situations. For all I know one of the constructors you run is causing the problem.

Comment: It appears that most of the time is spent between the GetAssemblies enumeration and its filtering, but globally, every action(like checking if the type implements the interface) is slower. The computer is a beast and only use 5-10% of its CPU during this period, not much disk usage and plenty of ram.

Comment: 20 seconds is already pretty absurd, 2 minutes is a sign of the beast.  You'll have to chase it yourself, start by disabling the installed anti-malware product and checking for network connection attempts.

Comment: @HansPassant : I agree, but we were searching all the classes implementing some interface, registering, generating classes based on xml we found, ... Really a lot of things. There is a refactoring planned to not use reflection that much(also I filtered the loading of so much libraries(like DevExpress). But this doesn't change that I've a ratio of *3 or *4 between my two uses cases.